# Detecting spam text over uploaded images (filtering script)?

Tags: image, filtering, ocr, spam

I'd like to know if is there a script or a filtering tool that is able to recognize SPAM text applied over user-uploaded images like here:

[image: IMAGE SPAM TEXT EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex question.  Short answer is NO.  Long answer is that this question consists of several discrete actions, which in combination and in controlled environments may provide you with what you need.

Text within image requires OCR or some other object detection to know it is text in the first place.  Depending on the color of the image, text, text background, and patterns, that text can be too integrated into the image itself, almost like captcha.

There was a Blog article on www.ocr-it.com website that describes how OCR can find text among images after the image gets binarized.  Sometimes light text on light background may dissapear completely.
http://www.ocr-it.com/user-scenario-process-digital-camera-pictures-and-ocr-to-extract-specific-numbers

If and when the text is detected in the image, then it can be filtered quite easily.

Comment: Perfect. Spam usually figure exactly as in this image ... so I think would be easy to find with a specific software. Can you list me some software's names able to do that (server side) as alternative to " www.ocr-it.com " ? Thanks